# Android studio update issue in windows

Tags: android-studio

When I upgrade android studio from 3.0.1 to 3.1 in windows 7, it shows this kind of error:
[image: Update conflit]

The error shows java.exe absent. I found the java file at location C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre\bin. I don't know what is the exact issue but I also tried by killing java.exe process from task manager but didn't work. Can anyone help?

Comment: Kindly verify which jdk or jre version you have installed.

Comment: @NitinKarande jre 1.8.0_161 and jdk 1.8.0_161

Comment: @NitinKarande do you have any possible solution about the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this error upgrading from 3.0.1 to 3.1.3. Removing that JRE from the path and installing another JRE fixed the issue.